# Cache writes with cachefilesd (non-shared mode) on Linux

Tags: linux, nfs, cache, network-share, disk-cache

I'm using cachefilesd as a read-cache for an NFS share. This is simple to set up and does what is says.

However, I would like to also cache written files. I.e., if I write `some.file`, and then I read `some.file`, I want this to be read from cache and not from the remote share.

I've come across some documentations online that specify a `non-shared` option, such as this here for [IBM AIX](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=system-cachefs-performance-impacts). This option is exactly what I want, but it is for CacheFS, not for cachefilesd.

**Question**: Is there an equivalent feature for cachefilesd? If so, how can I enable it?

**Bonus question**: Everywhere I look, documentations mention two available backends for FS-Cache: cachefilesd and CacheFS. However, I've not seen a single source that explains how to use CacheFS on Linux (only for Solaris, AIX, ...). *Does Linux have CacheFS-support at all?*

Comment: I've read the github repository notes about it, but I could not find, that only written will be cached

Comment: @djdomi I'm not sure I understand what you mean. My problem with cachefilesd is that the first read after a write still retrieves data from the remote server instead of returning the just-written data.